# Is it safe to address university administrators as "professors"?

Tags: etiquette, united-states, administration

Last time I had an appointment with one of the university advisors, she kept mentioning that she is going to "teach" later after the meeting. Long after the appointment I realized that I should have called her as "Professor XXXX" rather than "Ms. XXXX". However she does not have any scholars' websites, nor we could find out on internet that she indeed teaches some classes.

It is common in US to address college teachers as "Prof." I wonder if it is safe to address all university administrators as "professors", because if they are senior enough, most of them could have taught one or more college-level classes, orientation sections, or training sessions. Some of the administrators have ruling powers over the students in many scenarios, and it is not wise to insult them.

Comment: I added the United States tag to your question because in many countries "Professor" is a job title and therefore only used by actual professors, rather than generic teachers.

Comment: No. Many university administrators do not actually teach, and some fraction of these may actually think you are confused if you address them as "Professor". I am rather surprised that Googling didn't reveal that she taught classes in your case.

Comment: In addition, many administrators have a "higher" title than "Professor," e.g., "Dean," so it would be typical to address them as "Dean XXX."  And if it's not clear from university website or their business card, you can always ask them how they prefer to be addressed.

Comment: At my university, some advisors often led quiz sections for program/college intro classes, much like grad students do in other coursework. Maybe that's what she meant? She still wouldn't be a professor, but it would explain what she was doing w/o being a prof

Comment: @Kimball Dean Firstname or Dean Lastname?